# LuaLaTeX - Problem with defining Cambria Math only for special font types

Tags: fonts, math-mode, luatex

I've got a problem, that I can't fix. As soon as I try to use Cambria Math as font for `\mathscr` and `\mathbfscr` I get a

> "missing \endcsname inserted"

as error. I'm new to LuaLaTeX so I simply copied this line from a pdf document that I've found. Everything works fine when I use Cambria Math directly with `\setmathfont` instead of xits. So the font itself seems to be installed correctly.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\setmathfont[range={\mathscr,\mathbfscr}]{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
    Hello world!
\end{document}
```

Maybe someone can help me with that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Thanks for including an example with your question. Could you make it a [*minimum* working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and take out any lines that aren't necessary to reproduce the problem?

Comment: If I keep only the document class (without options), the `amsmath` package, the `unicode-math` package, and the line setting the math font to Cambria Math (I don't have the xits fonts, so I had to comment out those lines) I cannot reproduce this error. I did note some similar error with the `polyglossia` package in my brief tests...

Comment: I edited my question. I can reproduce the error with these lines as well!

Comment: Compiles without error here. May be updating will solve it.

Comment: Also no problems here. Are you using MiKTeX? If so, have a look here how to update: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108490/32374

Comment: Yes I'm using MiKTeX. I updated and he tells me that there are no possible updates. The error still exists...

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` just before `\begin{document}` and let us know the version for `unicode-math.sty` and `fontspec.sty` from the `.log` file? Mine are `v0.7e` and `v2.4` respectively. Also,  did you check for updates both in User mode and Admin mode?

Comment: I did check User Mode and Admin Mode as well. My versions are `v0.7e` for `unicode-math.sty` and `v2.4a` for `fontspec.sty`.

Comment: After I update my MiKTeX (to `fontspec v2.4a`), I can reproduce this error. You could consider submitting a bug report at https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/ since it seems to be a regression (unless it was changed on purpose)

Comment: According to the last commit, the `fixltx2e` package is no longer loaded by `fontspec`. If I put `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}[2006/03/24]` before `\documentclass`, the MWE compiles successfully (NB the commit message of that commit notes that it is recommended to load `fixltx2e` before `\documentclass`).

Comment: I can compile the MWE and my whole project now as well. Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: This post appears to be off-topic because it is about an issue in `unicode-math` that has been fixed: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/178 https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/commit/413f245feedeaa4200645338ea3f6c24e8481249 (@Sebastian Don't worry, this is just for house-keeping. Good question!)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a now resolved bug